# Issues reading file content from a directory within a Jar

Tags: java, file, jar, apache-commons

I found a lot of answers to this on SO but somehow am not able to integrate it with my code.

I have a jar which after opening a JarConnection and finding the Path for it looks like:

```
/Users/xyz/WTMS/target/WTMS.jar
```

I have a directory whose name is known to me as **vega-config-templates** with unknown files names under it like:

```
anonymous1.txt
anonymous2.txt
anonymous3.txt
.
.
.
```

Code:

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(directoryPath);
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    final Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        final JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        final String entryName = entry.getName();

        System.out.println("Entry name "+entryName);
        if (entryName.startsWith("/vega-config-templates")) {
            arrayList.add(entryName.replace('/', File.separatorChar));
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I am able to access the top level directory as a Jar Entry with name "vega-config-templates" but over this i want to do something like :

```
FileUtils.listFiles(directory, null, true)
```

then I want to get the content of these `Collection<Files>` , files, on the go, which I am not able to do with JarEntry **as it not drilling down the top level directories.**

Neither can I apply traditional file traversals over these URIs to open this directory and then iterate over it as a simple `File directory = new File(jarUri+"/vega-config-templates")`;

How do i dynamically iterate over the files and get file objects so i can extract the content over each one of them , all under a known directory within a jar.

Comment: Did u try reading as a stream>

Comment: I do not know the file names under the directory to read as an input stream